# Linux tool dc gives "stack underflow" error

Tags: shell, dc

I'm trying to calculate a floating number via shell. When I execute the following line, the dc tool fails.

```
dc -e "4000 0.531 / p"
```

First, I was thinking that the problem was related to the floating precision. Then, I tried to change the divider with an integer. Unfortunately, the result is the same.

```
dc -e "4000 1000 / p"
```

Both of the executions above gives the same error:

> dc: stack underflow

Host CPU is ARM-Cortex A53 placed inside the Zynq Ultrascale+ SoC. What would be the reason? How can I solve it?

### Additional Info

The output of `dc --version` also gives the same output.

> dc: stack underflow

Luckily, the `dc --help` works and shows the version as follows.

> BusyBox v1.24.1 (2021-12-08 08:10:27 UTC) multi-call binary.

The output of the `type dc` is as follows

> dc is hashed (/usr/bin/dc)

Comment: Please post the output of `dc --version` or `dc --help`. `ARM-Cortex A53 placed inside the Zynq Ultrascale+ SoC` What `dc` implementation is runnning there? Hm.. it should have worked. Are you _100%_ sure there is nothing else happening? What does `type dc` outputs? What is the shell you are using?

Comment: oookkk, I can reproduce with `docker run -ti --rm busybox:1.24`. The good thing - update to busybox 1.3x and it seems fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the reason?

Busybox `dc` does not take any `-e` argument. Because `-e` is parsed as `-` followed by command `e`, `-` tries to pop two values and the stack is empty.

> How can I solve it?

Just:

```
dc "4000 0.531 / p"
```

The proper way is anyway to pipe the data to stdin.

```
echo "4000 0.531 / p" | dc
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. [Here](https://perso.esiee.fr/~llorense/Labo5201/mc528x/PDFs/_read4-d5280.pdf) is the documentation of BusyBox's `dc` tool. As you stated, it doesn't accept `-e` as an operand.

Comment: You posted some link to some word document. The documentation can be found on busybox.net official site https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html . Also source code is the documenttion: https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/dc.c#L291